# Sensor applet doesn't save settings after restart

Tags: 11.04, indicator

I installed the sensor applet in Ubuntu 11.04 to check the temperature. Everything works fine; however, changes I make to the preferences are lost after every restart. How can I save my setup?

Comment: Is this in Unity or Classic mode?

Comment: Hello Mandy, it is in Unity mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug -- https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-sensors/+bug/782047

It's marked as Fix Comitted, but the fixed version is not available in project's PPA (last update in May).